# NVIDIA GeForce 9400M capable of OpenGL 3.3 or 4.0 on a Mac?

Tags: visual-studio, nvidia, parallels, osx-snow-leopard, bootcamp

I need to work with OpenGL 3.3 or 4.0 and I am using a MacBook6,1 (Intel Core 2 Duo, 4GB RAM, 2,26 GHz) with a NVIDIA GeForce 9400M graphic card. Is this card capable of performing OpenGL 3.3 or 4.0 things? From the cards specifics I coud not figure out if its possible!
We need to work with Visual Studio as well. Is it enough to run it on Parallels Desktop or better BootCamp, you have any experience? 
Thanks for any help!

greets Jules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nVidia 9400M and the newer 320M support OpenGL 3.3 under Windows 7. However, running a project build using OpenGL 3.2 in Parallels Desktop and Win7 does not work for me. I suggest using BootCamp for the best OpenGL support.

Comment: Parallels knowledge-base: [What OpenGL version is supported in Parallels Desktop 8](http://kb.parallels.com/en/115487)? (Answer: only up to 2.1 as of Parallels Desktop 8/9, at the moment.)

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to do Visual studio and OpenGL work on a Parallels desktop without any trouble.  I'm using a Macbook Pro (Intel Core i7 2.7 Ghz, 4 GB Ram, Intel Graphics 384 MB)

You should be fine.